# Building jar file (htsjdk jar) with Ant

Tags: java, ubuntu, ant, vcf-vcard

HTSJDK is a library for accessing common file formats, such as SAM and VCF. I want to build the HTSJDK jar. In the documentation page says that I have to use Ant for that. So I installed Ant and run the command:

> ant htsjdk-jar

But I get this error:

> compile-samtools:
>
> [javac] /home/usr/Documents/samtools-htsjdk/build.xml:241: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
>
> [javac] Compiling 410 source files to /home/usr/Documents/samtools-htsjdk/classes
>
> [javac] javac: invalid target release: 1.8
>
> [javac] Usage: javac <options> <source files>
>
> [javac] use -help for a list of possible options
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> /home/usr/Documents/samtools-htsjdk/build.xml:96: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>
> /home/usr/Documents/samtools-htsjdk/build.xml:241: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

There is something wrong with the *build.xml* file. Here it is the beginning of the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<project name="htsjdk" basedir="." default="all">

    <property name="src" value="src/java"/>
    <property name="src.test" value="src/tests"/>
    <property name="src.test.java" value="${src.test}/java"/>
    <property name="lib" value="lib"/>
    <property name="dist" value="dist"/>
    <property name="classes" value="classes"/>
    <property name="classes.test" value="testclasses"/>
    <property name="scripts" value="src/scripts"/>
    <property name="test.output" value="dist/test"/>

    <property name="javac.target" value="1.8"/>
    <property name="javac.debug" value="true"/>

    <!-- Get GIT hash, if available, otherwise leave it blank.  -->

    <property name="repository.revision" value=""/>
    <property name="htsjdk-version" value="2.0.1"/>
    <property name="htsjdk-version-file" value="htsjdk.version.properties"/>
    <property name="testng.verbosity" value="2"/>
    <property name="test.debug.port" value="5005" />  <!-- override on the command line if desired -->
```

Please, can someone tell me what to do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The javac task in the build.xml (which tells ant what to do) specifies a Java target version of 1.8 (which means Java 8). Seems like you are trying to compile with a lower Java version. You can check your installed Java version using `javac -version`.

Comment: That was it. I was trying with 1.7 after I installed 1.8 it worked. Thank you!